# Queue wget scripts

Tags: ssh, wget

i have php website crawler  that  build wget scripts

crontab that command to open folder and sh all files build via php

```
cd /home/sen/public_html/akwam/orders/
for i in *
do
      sh /home/sen/public_html/akwam/orders/"$i"
    rm -rf /home/sen/public_html/akwam/orders/"$i"
done
```

php create files end  with .txt at folder to run latter with ssh

```
  $ddd = " wget -b -nc --no-check-certificate   $newcommand  \"$url\"  -q -o  /dev/null      ";


  file_put_contents( './orders/' . $t . '.txt', $ddd );
```

there a way to Queue wget scripts to not flood(high load) at urls all at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found way to make it like Queue

first remove `-b` from wget command

second improve sh script to not run one by one , no

collect all at one file line by line

```
do
      cat /home/sen/public_html/akwam/orders/"$i" >>  /plex/final.txt
         echo >> /plex/final.txt
      rm -rf /home/sen/public_html/akwam/orders/"$i"
done
```